# How to pass a string on a onclick method

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I have a html like this

```
<button class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" 
onclick="updatepage(TestString)" data-toggle="modal">Test String</button>
```

and the function is

```
function updatepage(variable){
 // some stuff
}
```

I'm getting an error "TestString is not defined", and if I put

```
onclick="updatepage("TestString")"
```

I get a syntax error.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: `onclick="updatepage('TestString')"`  Watch your quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use single quotes as string delimiters:

```
onclick="updatepage('TestString')"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
onClick="updatepage(\'' + TestString + '\')"
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the `'`?  And what's with the `+`?

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="updatepage(" + escape(JSON.stringify(TestString)) + ")"
```

You should consider using the EventListener API. This notation is limited to values that are easily serializable. You can not pass-by-reference, for instance.